# Return the selected elements of a matrix into

Tags: c#

I need a method to return the select elements in a 2D array where the the position of the elements are stored in other arrays as follow:

```
double[,] data = new double[4, 4] { 

{ 12, -51, 4, 5 }, 

{ 6, 5, -68, 4 }, 

{ -4, 200, -410, -500 }, 

{ 1000, 8, 6, 700 } };

UInt32[] IndR = new UInt32[2] { 1, 3 };

UInt32[] IndC = new UInt32[2] { 0, 2 };

double[,] B = MyMethod(data, IndR, IndC);
```

It should return:

```
{

{6, -68}

{1000, 6}

}
```

Comment: Math.Net : https://numerics.mathdotnet.com/Matrix.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I shudder to think what the next question will be

**Given**

```
public static T[,] SliceAndDice<T>(T[,] source, uint[] xs, uint[] ys)
{
   var result = new T[xs.Length, 2];
   for (var y = 0; y < ys.Length; y++)
      for (var x = 0; x < xs.Length; x++)  
         result[x,y] = source[  xs[x], ys[y]];
   return result;
}
```

Usage

```
double[,] data = new double[4, 4] {   
   { 12, -51, 4, 5 },   
   { 6, 5, -68, 4 },   
   { -4, 200, -410, -500 },  
   { 1000, 8, 6, 700 } };

var IndR = new uint[] { 1, 3 };    
var IndC = new uint[] { 0, 2 };

var b = SliceAndDice(data, IndR, IndC);

for (int i = 0; i < b.GetLength(0); i++)
{
   for (int j = 0; j < b.GetLength(0); j++)
      Console.Write(b[i,j] + " ");
   Console.WriteLine();
}
```

**Output**

```
6 -68
1000 6
```

Comment: Is there a way to utilize .Select  .Where commands here?

Comment: People told me that the program runs faster with .Select or .where commands. 
Is that even true?

Comment: @SignalSharp no not in most cases, it can actually be slower. Also there is no easy or useful way to put this into linq when dealing with multi dimentional arrays.